# Sorting by popularity ( weekly / monthly / yearly / all time)

Tags: gui-design, sorting

I'm looking for examples of UGC sorting by popularity (by votes and also comments). Currently I have a dropdown with the following sorting options.

- Most voted *(all time)*
- Most commented *(all time)*
- 7 categories one below the other

The idea is to let the user choose a **time frame: week, month, year and historical**. Is it OK to add this options in the dropdown itself? Or is it better to go with another UI pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can do something like this site, see image below[image]

however, it might be a bit convoluted for your needs.

So, another option could be as follow:

[image]

obviously, you can (and should) load the sub menu in closed state, I'm showing them in open for visualization purposes. Please note the separators as well, they're important.

With the above, we could easily get to something like this as well:

[image]

Obviously, you could use any of the 2 samples above, only that loading the sub menu on the side (in this case the arrows should point to the right)

And a final option could be to make a 2-steps option:

1. **Step 1**

User *selects a filter taxonomy*, for example **Most voted**

2. **Step 2**

Dropdown with taxonomies fade to show only the *time frame variables* and  "apply filter" / "back to filters" buttons

---

While this might seems more complex, it's actually less confusing and takes only one additional click, which is highly compensated by the fact the user gets way more reduced friction by having no additional alternatives on screen

In any case, you'll need to test out and see which one works better for you

Comment: Thanks Devin for your clear explanation! I think I will consider the second option since it's more suitable for the responsive nature of the site. I wish I had enough reputation to give you an upvote.

Comment: ah no worries, if you like it just mark the answer as accepted so the question doesn't keep open